# Document opened with word automation always displays template save dialog

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation

We have documents that have been created with a template. In our app the document can be viewed, which lauches an word automation Open method, as shown below.

When the user closes word, a Save dialog bow is always displayed ("Want to save your changes to .dotx?"), and this happens even though no changes were made to the main document.  The template portion is never touched.

How can we stop this dialog from displaying?

Code:

```
public class WordHelper
{
    private Word._Application _app = null;

    public WordHelper(bool visible = false, bool maximize = false)
    {
        try
        {
            _app = new Word.Application();
            _app.Application.Visible = visible;
            if (maximize)
                _app.Application.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
            else
                _app.Application.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal;

            _app.Application.Caption = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Trim(); 
            _pid = UtilityHelper.GetPidByWindowTitle(_app.Application.Caption);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScreenHelper.DisplayException(ex, "Error on launch of Word document generation", this.GetType().Name, new StackFrame().GetMethod().Name);
        }
    }

    public void OpenDocument(string fileName, bool readOnly, string readPassword, string writePassword)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            {
                _app.Documents.Open(
                    fileName,
                    Type.Missing,
                    readOnly,
                    false,
                    readPassword,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    writePassword,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);
                _app.Application.Caption = fileName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in OpenDocument" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code that saves the document or fires when you close the document you need to specifically tell it to either show the dialog or not for example checkout this post http://codekea.com/vkgYaaR7wgP2/microsoftofficeinteropworddocument-wont-prompt-to-save-changes-to-single-document-without-applicationquit.html

Comment: The process that originally saved the document is not relevant - what is significant is that the document was originally created with a template.

In regard to closing the document, that is not done programmically in this case - it is done by the user when they are finished viewing it.  That is when the Save popup appears that I am trying to get rid of.